# importing ReactNode in typescript module fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, types, typescript-typings

I have a create-react-app that has a `types` directory in `src` with the following:

**testapp-components.d.ts**

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Option {
  label: ReactNode;
  value: string;
  [key: string]: ReactNode;
}

declare module "@testApp/components";
```

However, when I use it in my component as such...

```
// @testApp/components is an internal library I've installed. OptionSelector is a custom react component.
import { OptionSelector } from @testApp/components; 

... other React code ...

const [options, setOptions] = useState<Option[]>([]);
```

It gives me the following errors:

1. `TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@testApp/components` under the `import { OptionSelector } ...`
2. `TS2304: Cannot find name Option` under the useState

If I remove the `import { ReactNode } ...` and change the `ReactNode` references to `any` both errors are gone...

Changing the filename to `.d.tsx` does not fix the problem.

I've also tried this:

```
declare module "@testApp/components" {
    export interface Option {
       label: any;
       value: string;
       [key: string]: any;
    }
};
```

Which produces the same error for the useState, but gives me a new error for the `import { OptionSelector } ...`:

1. `TS2305: Module @testApp/components has no exported member OptionSelector`